# Node.js callback ordering

Tags: node.js

I have been coding in Node.js:

```
var sql = ' SELECT 1 AS re';
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    connection.query(sql,function(err,rows){
      if(err){connection.rollback(function (e) {throw err;});}
      else{
        console.log('foo');
      }
   }); 
}
setTimeout(function(){ console.log('b }, 50);
```

Can I lined output up exactly? Like: `foo --> bar`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not know what you are asking. Are you saying you want the two `console.log()` statements to output in order?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap your code either in `async` or in a form of a `promise`.

For Instance:

```
var sql = 'SELECT 1 AS re';

var count = 0;
async.whilst(
  function() {
    return count < 10;
  },
  function(done) {
    count++;
    connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
      if(err) 
        connection.rollback(function(e) { done(); });
      else {
        console.log('foo');
      done();
      }
    });
  },
  function(err) {
    console.log('bar');
  });
```

Now this will be sequential. Again, if this isn't what you were asking. I'd suggest to please update your question, so that we have a better idea of what the problem is, or at least what are your intentions of doing.